# How do I stop Open Office from automatically changing the date format?

Tags: openoffice, openoffice-writer

I am trying to enter a date in a document with the following format:

```
1 September 2010
```

However, OpenOffice insists on changing it to:

```
01/09/10
```

I've looked in the AutoCorrect options and elsewhere and have been unable to find a way to disable this annoying behaviour.  Any suggestions?

Comment: What application are you talking about (Writer, Calc, Impres...)? And which language settings do you use?

Comment: @sleske Writer.  My language is set to English (UK).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is a special auto-correct behaviour that is only active for tables in Writer (not in Calc). It is controlled under:

Tools > Options > OpenOffice.org Writer > Table > Input in tables > Number recognition

Uncheck that option to disable the autocorrection.

Answer (score 1):

changing the date format is simple just follow these steps:
in OpenOffice Writer go to Insert > Fields > Other > select Date from the first box > Date fixed from the second box > Choose the format that u want to use from the third box then Click Insert.

edit: you also can add more formats from the same window if u want by double clicking on Additional Formats.....

Comment: That's not really what was asked. The poster didn't ask how to insert a date in a certain format, but how to disable the autoformatting when typing it in. Your answer does not do this.

Comment: thats what i thought when i first read the topic but when i copied and pasted that date into a new writer file it wasnt changed by the auto-correction, also i typed some dates and saved the file and made a print preview and it didnt change so i thought maybe he means how to use another auto formating way than the pre-defined one

Answer (score 1):

For Openoffice Writer:

Change date autocorrect style

1. Go to Table.
2. In Number Format Menu - change Language to English UK or whatever you need - choose date style you want in Format.

Answer (score 0):

Just click right mouse button where you fill date and:

> formatcell -> number -> date -> formatcode -> DD MMMM YY -> then click OK button.

Your date related problem should be solved.

Answer (score 0):

You can start with an apostrophe to ensure that it is recognised as a text and hence doesn't autocomplete.